# What is the difference in GetCurrentCtx() and SP.ClientContext.get_current()?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

Is there some reference to this subject?

Both methods return completely different objects.

Answer (score 7):

GetCurrentCtx() can be run only in list views and gives you ContextInfo object with some useful properties. SP.ClientContext.get_current() gives you the javascript form of SPContext which you can use to retrieve, modfiy sharepoint stuff from javascript. So they are different things.

[image]